# ES file explorer has been denied permission for an interactive shell

Tags: root-access, file-permissions

I have a rooted Nexus 7. I've been using ES File Explorer along with it. I have been able to navigate through files, after having set Tools/Root Explorer and turning it on. But now, I can no longer do this. When I go to turn on the Root Explorer, I get this message:
*ES file explorer has been denied permission for an interactive shell*
I must have change some other setting for this to happen, but I don't know what it is.
Can you suggest what I might do get this back?

Comment: Have you checked with your Superuser/SuperSU app whether you accidentally *denied* access for *ES File Explorer*?

Comment: If you have updated ES or SuperSU you may need to re-grant SU permission. Open SuperSU and update binaries, if necessary, and check as @Izzy said if you have denied access to ES file explorer.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I went into SuperSU and granted permission.

Comment: @RossC: Post your comment as an answer please.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest a solution for this....

As I was facing the same issue regarding the Permission Denied For ES Explorer

Go To KingUser Application in your Device (App available after root), you will find the list of applications which are in Allow / Deny state

Here, you will find the ES Explorer (must be in a Deny State..)

Change it to "Allow" and Go To ES Explorer and change the Option "On" for Root Explorer...

Comment: Didn't you read the comments from the question? The answer lies within SU.